# Mustache include template

Tags: jquery, html, mustache

I'm new to Mustache and I'm working on a website already using it. I have a set of Mustache templates in a folder in this site. They are called with Sekizai tags in the main html like this:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
...
<body>

    {% block body_content %}{% endblock %}

    {% mustachejs "dashboard_module" %}
    {% mustachejs "dashboard_add_module" %}
    {% mustachejs "dashboard_empty_module" %}
    {% mustachejs "login_popup" %}
    {% mustachejs "add_account_types_popup" %}
    {% mustachejs "add_account_manual_popup" %}
    {% mustachejs "add_account_success_popup" %}
    {% mustachejs "chart_linearprogress" %}
    {% mustachejs "adviser_popover" %}

        {% mustachejs "add_event_popup" %}

</body>
</html>
```

this produces script tags like:

```
<script>Mustache.TEMPLATES=Mustache.TEMPLATES||
{};Mustache.TEMPLATES['add_event_popup']='<div id="AddAccountsPopup" class="add-event-popup">\n
<div class="addAccountsContainer">\n ... </script>
```

Now in another js file I want to show on a click event one of these templates, like:

```
function my func(){
            var evnt_btn = $('.add-evnt-btn');
            var template;
            // get mustache template
        template = $( Mustache.render( 'add_event_popup' ));

            evnt_btn.click(function(){

                template.show();
            });
}
```

What's in myfunc() doesn't work of course! How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
var template = Mustache.template('add_event_popup').render(null);
```